# How Graphics/Graphics2D are implemented?

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d, java-2d

As seen in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html), most of the methods on rendering are `abstract`.

- How are they implemented?
- How do Java2D draw a square on my screen? (the answer I'm looking for is not "via 2 triangles")
- Where is the code doing that?
- How can I view it?

I think they are implemented natively, meaning the code responsible for the rendering is probably in C (or maybe not and tucked away in some old `sun` package). I'd be happy if someone could point me to the implementation of these methods. I'm on Windows and I only care about the Windows implementation of said methods.

Comment: Most of the code for these classes surely is in native code, code which I don't believe is available for mere mortals such as us.

Comment: That is surely bad news, as I'm implementing the same interface using Vulkan :/

Comment: Before undertaking such an effort, you may want to check whether JavaFX meets your performance needs.

Comment: It's implemented either through OpenGL or DirectX but is platform dependent.